# connecting to weblogic server via webapp and pulling the servers attributes

Tags: java, web-applications, weblogic, jndi

I am working on a java web app that will pull some information(cpu usage, java heap size, etc) from a weblogic server and display it on a webpage. right now the server im connecting to is local but i will expand on that later. my problem is the way that im connecting seems to access the configuration side of the server and i cant get the data that i want. i am very new with java and weblogic.  here is my code(you will see some redundancy, i was testing different techniques out.)

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NameNotFoundException;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import javax.naming.Context;
import weblogic.jndi.*;
import weblogic.management.configuration.ServerMBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class getStatus
 */
public class getStatus extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
ServerMBean beanOne = null;
String beanTwo = null;
Context ctx = null;
InitialContext ictx = null;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public getStatus() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {


      Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
      ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
      ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://localhost:7001");
      ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
      ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "welcome1");

      try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
        try { 
               beanOne = (ServerMBean) ctx.lookup("ServerMBean");
               beanOne.getName();


            }catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
              // binding does not exist
                System.out.println("bean not found :(");
            }catch (NamingException e) {
              // a failure occurred
                System.out.println("bean not found D:");
            }
        // Use the context in your program
      }
      catch (NamingException e) {
          System.out.println("no context :(");
        // a failure occurred
      }
      finally {
        try {(ctx).close();}
        catch (Exception e) {
          // a failure occurred
            System.out.println("no context D:");
        }
      }
      weblogic.jndi.Environment environment = new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
      environment.setInitialContextFactory(weblogic.jndi.Environment.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
      environment.setProviderUrl("t3://localhost:7001");
      environment.setSecurityPrincipal("weblogic");
      environment.setSecurityCredentials("welcome1");

      try{
      ictx = (InitialContext) environment.getInitialContext();
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("no initial context :(");
      }

      try { 
           beanTwo = (String) ictx.lookup("ejb.serviceBean");
        }catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
          // binding does not exist
            System.out.println("bean not found :(");
        }catch (NamingException e) {
          // a failure occurred
            System.out.println("bean not found D:");
        }
      try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           //a failure occurred
        }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

i need a way to connect to the weblogic server pull out certain attributes and set variables equal to their values so i could use them later. and again im very new at this so i might be completely off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do looks like basic JMX bean polling, have you read a tutorial online? There are a lot, starting from the [official](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/) one and many other if you search "JMX tutorial" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: i will take a look. ive been thrust into a position that needs to know how to use this so anything helps.

Comment: also i am supposed to get the cpu usage on the server that i check but was informed that i may not be able to do that through this approach. i was told that a good way to get that kind of info was through unix. do you have some more tutorials that i could read up on for that as well?